# Optimise Google Search Result

Tags: search, seo

I am looking for search google search result more like this: http://goo.gl/T3xUnC where many pages are shown. But instead I am getting this: http://goo.gl/it5EKh. I am wasted week finding good solution. Please help me out here...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about search-engine optimization rather than programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be off topic but a you need to have a sitemap and robots.txt (pointing to sitemap.xml)

robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Sitemap: /sitemap.xml
```

sitemap.xml (Wich contains all of your url's)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/folder1/</loc>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

The next time google crawls it will index your page like you want it (this can take a while, so don't expect that it will work tomorrow).

Comment: I also noticed the google suggestion: http://goo.gl/5LP4Vz and then it worked.

Comment: @user3222855 please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the HTML conventions and structure it well. If you have enough visitors(so quality content is very important) they will link to your page(backlinks) and after a while Google will pick this up and with a bit of luck they will generate the site links for you.